AWS OpenSearch: can't evaluate on aggregator: sum
In the AWS OpenSearch, I have enabled the SQL plugin to use the SQL queries.
{
  "transient" : {
    "plugins.sql.enabled" : true
  }
}

I'm using the following query:
select `revenue` as `status`, sum(`_ingest.totalPrice`) as value, count(*) as count, date_format(receiptDate, 'y-MM') as aggDate, 'revenue' as type from revenues WHERE `_uid`='1234' and ((millis>=1706745600000 and millis<=1717199999999) or millis=-1) GROUP by `status`, aggDate

The above query is working fine and giving the correct results but sometimes the query failed with the following response:
{
  "error": {
    "details": "can't evaluate on aggregator: sum",
    "reason": "Invalid SQL query",
    "type": "ExpressionEvaluationException"
  },
  "status": 400
}

Not sure why the query is failing. Any idea or workaround to resolve this?

Were you able to find any solution of this problem?

Not yet. For now, just added the retry if the query is failed
